# how to retrieve big data from Database into Gridview in ASP.Net? without paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview in which I have bind data from Database. The Problem is The data is approximately 12000+ rows and It is taking too much time to load the gridview. I don't want paging in my Grid. So NO pagination. It is possible to make it fast retrieval? I am getting data through Stored Procedure from Database and I have uploaded my database in Cloud.

**This is my Stored Procedure**

```
    SELECT 
    A.ItemCode as 'Item Code'
        ,rtrim(A.PartItemNo)  as 'Item No'
        ,rtrim(A.ItemDesc)  as 'Item Description'
        ,rtrim(IsNull(isnull(Sum(B.INQty),0) + Sum(B.RecQty) + Sum(B.PurRetQty) + Sum(B.RetQty) - ((Sum(B.IssQty) + Sum(B.ChargeOutQty)) ), 0)) As Quantity  
        ,A.ProdCode
        ,A.PurchaseRate
        ,A.SaleRate
        ,A.Source

    from Item A 
    Left outer Join ItemStock B 
    On A.ItemCode=B.ItemCode 
    And A.DealerCode=B.DealerCode 

    Where  (A.DealerCode=@DealerCode and @Category = '')
    or (A.DealerCode=@DealerCode and @Category = 'P' and A.LubeFlag = 'N')
    or (A.DealerCode=@DealerCode and @Category = 'L' and A.LubeFlag = 'Y')
    or (A.DealerCode=@DealerCode and @Category = 'PL' AND Source not in ('C.K.D.' , 'LOCAL'))

    Group by A.ItemCode,A.ItemDesc,A.PartItemNo,A.ProdCode,A.PurchaseRate,A.SaleRate,A.Source Order by A.ItemCode asc
```

**This is the Code in C# Asp.Net**

```
sQuery = "test '" + Session["DealerCode"].ToString() + "', 'P'";
 if (myFunc.ExecuteQuery(sQuery, ref ds))
{
Session["Parts"] = ds;
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
   {
       gvParts.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; gvParts.DataBind();
       gvParts.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
   }
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd recommend against presenting the user with 12,000+ records on a single page for usability reasons (ignoring the obvious performance issues).

Comment: Clients Requirement Sir. Basically it is the parts of Vehicles, we need them on when we are using  .

Comment: Not sure what is slow on your site. Put some stop watch in code to see if the database connection and how long it takes. So you can see if it is the data connection or rendering that is slow. Then you can maybe add some caching, or change the render to plain html table and not gridview etc.